# Envato can allow inline CSS for background-image but reviewers comment is confusing me

Tags: php, wordpress, background-image

I have faced a problem. I have converted a theme for ThemeForest market place. But my theme got soft reject and reviewer mentioned this issue

> Scripts and styles should not be hardcoded anywhere in your theme or added any other way but with wp_enqueue_* hook and to be added from the functions file. This includes custom JS/CSS. 
>   For inline styles use: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/ and for scripts https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/"

After that, I have found some inline CSS on my theme which is used for background-image. Then I have solved inline CSS issue by using flollowing link functions `wp_add_inline_style()`, `get_theme_mod()` and `set_theme_mod()`.

But in the Envato help author page can allow inline CSS for `background-image`. Which is :
`<div id="header-background" style="background-image: url( <?php echo esc_url( 
'$header-background' ); ?> );"></div>`

Described in the below link

https://help.author.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000479946-WordPress-Theme-Coding-Requirements#h_7520408803181522300441040

Now my question is- "I have used inline CSS background-image (post-thumbnail) for blog post which are dynamic. If I follow Envato reviewer instruction then I can't use inline CSS `background-image` for blog post but Envato help author page can permitted inline CSS for only `background-image`."

What should I do now?

Comment: do you have <link rel> tags in your header.php file? ex:  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abc.css" >

Comment: @Vishwa I have not added any stylesheet in the header.php

Comment: or scripts files either in header or footer.php files? **wp_enqueue_* hook and to be added from the functions file** means you incorrectly added css/js file and also try to eliminate inline styles as much as possible.